# Can we have a graphing tool for Math.SE and Physics.SE?

Tags: feature-request

Graphing tool is very important for answering and asking some questions in Math and Physics.

Physics also require diagrams for explaining the scenario in the problem and in some answers in mechanics as making Free_Body_diagrams etc.

Edit:
Graphing tool must include the function plotting and drawing some free shapes ( just as in paint , that will also cover the physics FBD and diagram part ) .

Here are few examples with images imported from external sources

- [circle of inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382721/circle-of-inversion)
- [help on a geometry problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382139/help-on-a-geometry-problem)

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you mean by graphing tool. Something to plot functions? Or a completely free-form vector drawing program?

Comment: @MadScientist Yes to plot functions. And physics also require free form drawing tool too.

Comment: @MadScientist I have seen you on maths.se once. Don't you feel there should be something like that/

Comment: This would be better posted on the particular site metas. Add links to questions that you think would benefit from the graphing tool.

Comment: I think a graphing tool could certainly be useful on MSE, a free-form drawing tool is probably too complicated. But these are really two very different feature requests, and I would post them on the appropriate child meta, maybe with some more motivation and justification for the request, and some suggestions on which open source javascript libraries could be used. You need to convince your own community that this is a very useful tool, and then you need to convince SE that it is worth their time to implement it.

Comment: @ChrisF: Hmm.. i'll try finding some , but most people (not me) have mathematica on their pc and get the graphing done by it.They just upload that image afterwards.

Comment: I can see people using MSE as a graphing tool, if this is done right. Not sure that's best, but per site meta is.

Comment: @exploringnet I wouldn't say most people have and use Mathematica (except on [mathematica.SE]). I've seen TikZ (free), Gnuplot (free), matplotlib (free), Excel, Origin, Wolfram Alpha, and others for plotting, and TikZ (free), Inkscape (free), GIMP (free), MS Paint, and others used for arbitrary graphics.