# How do I tag a question in chat?

Tags: support, tags, chat

No really.  I can't figure out how to do this.  Nor can I find it on meta.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9253971#9253971

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
Sorry if you meant something else.

I now see it like posting this :
http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1367565#1367565

It is done by typing

`[tag:cv-pls]http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1367565#1367565`

And you are done.

---

**Earlier answer:**

just directly enter the link into the chat , it will enter that question in the chat like this:

Posting link as such `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179167/can-we-have-a-graphing-tool-for-math-se-and-physics-se` in chat gives this;
[image]